# How to convert a .tif PIL image to a torch tensor?

Tags: python-imaging-library, torch

I have some .tif images and I'm reading them in as PIL image.
I know there is a `ToPILimage` transform

but I could not find a `from_PILimage()` akin to `from_numpy()`

as of right now I have this ugly looking thing:

```
img = torch.from_numpy(np.array(Image.open('path/image.tif')))
```

Could you show me a better way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to `torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage()`, you can use `torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()` directly. Example from PyTorch [docs](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/pytorch-pil-to-tensor-and-vice-versa/6312/10)

There's also the functional equivalent `torchvision.functional.to_tensor()`.

```py
img = Image.open('someimg.png')

import torchvision.transforms.functional as TF
TF.to_tensor(img)

from torchvision import transforms
transforms.ToTensor()(img)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, silly me tried this one, passing img as an argument earlier, thanks again! works perfectly